# How can I read a structure from a file, replacing the contents of self?

Tags: rust

I am trying to read the whole structure with one file operation to `self`. The `load` function is supposed to be a member function of the structure:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct ItIsMe<T> {
    pub value1: T
    // ...
    // A lot of items like this
}

trait ItIsMeTrait {
}

impl<T> ItIsMe<T> {
    pub fn new(v: T) -> Self {
        ItIsMe {
            value1: v
        }
    }

    pub fn load(&mut self, file: &mut File) -> io::Result<()> {
        // An attempt to read the whole structure
        //unsafe{ file.read(self as *mut Self as *mut u8)?;}
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut it = ItIsMe::new(55);
    println!("value = {}", it.value1);

    let mut file = File::open("path_to_file")?;
    it.load(&mut file)?;

    println!("value = {}", it.value1);

    Ok(())
}
```

I could not find the proper way to express this.

I am aware of this function that permits reading a structure from a file:

```
pub fn read_struct<T, R: Read>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<T> {
    let num_bytes = ::std::mem::size_of::<T>();
    unsafe {
        let mut mem = ::std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init();
        let ptr = slice::from_raw_parts_mut(&mut mem as *mut T as *mut u8, num_bytes);
        match reader.read_exact(ptr) {
            Ok(()) => Ok(mem),
            Err(e) => {
                ::std::mem::forget(mem);
                Err(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this function reads into another instance of the structure. Is it possible to de-serialize a structure directly to itself (`self`)?

Comment: **DO NOT USE** that `read_struct` function—it invokes undefined behaviour!

Comment: Specifically, `MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()` (and more generally calling `assume_init()` before actually initializing) is something you should never do.

Comment: Reading the raw bytes straight into a non `repr(C)` struct also invokes undefined behavior- the default representation has no layout guarantees.

Comment: Added #[repr(C)]. Thank you

Comment: Your code is still a bad idea because you have a generic type inside your `repr(C)` struct and the generic type isn't guaranteed to be `repr(C)` itself.

Comment: I cannot find a proper way to implement this even if no generic types are involved. Let's say ```<T>``` is substituted by ```u32```

Comment: You'd do the exact thing that your `read_struct` function does (ignoring how good or bad it is), but converting `&mut Self` into the `*mut u8`.

Comment: Your comment has helped. Thank you! Would you mind to publish it as an answer that I would mark it as an accepted solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde) crate. Serde lets you quickly and painlessly serialize and deserialize structs to and from various file formats. Simply add the serde and serde-your-favorite-filetype crates to your `Cargo.toml` to get started. A simple example:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.126
use serde_json::from_reader; // 1.0.64

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: T, //other fields...
}

fn main() {
    let data: &[u8] = br#"{
            "bar":27
    }"#;
    let deserialized: Foo<i32> = from_reader(data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", deserialized);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a71890ce22de67f0b3f7630e7bc95b5)

You could also use unsafe code but I would highly recommend against that- it is much easier and safer to use serde with your favorite file format to do this.